# Show that the following is a valid pmf

Tags: statistics

Let $X$ have the pmf $$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^{(x-1)} \quad x=1,2,3,\ldots$$

Show that $p(x)$ is a valid pmf.

I know that the sum of $p(x) = 1$, though I'm not sure how to begin showing how it equals 1.

Comment: It's a geometric series. Can you see why? Hint: Find the common ratio. Do you know the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @quasi Oh I see now. I found the common ratio and applied it to the sum of an infinite geometric series formula, and got 1. Thanks!